# Launching an external browser with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I've written a program for handling putting html files in and talking them out of a cms. In this program I have some code so that you can preview on different browsers. However, when I run it I get an unhandled exception stating "Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided."

- This only happens when trying to launch chrome or firefox, IE works fine.
- It only happens when I run my program through Advanced Installer and install it onto my machine, it works when building it straight out of VS2012 in release mode.

My code is as follows:

```
if (chk_ExternalBrowser.Checked)
{
    string ffTempFilePath = "\"" + tempFilePath + "\"";//tempFilePath is an absolute path to the html file

    Process.Start(browserPaths[1], ffTempFilePath);//launch FF, browserPaths[1] contains an absolute path to firefox.exe
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

**UPDATE:**
The error was caused because I did not surround the content of browserPaths[1] with quotes. Now I get no error, but a windows explorer window is opened instead of the firefox browser. My ammended code is below:

```
if (chk_ExternalBrowser.Checked)
{
    string ffTempFilePath = "\"" + tempFilePath + "\"";//after this line ffTempFilePath == \"C:\\Users\\<username ommitted>\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Local_IMP\\Local_IMP\\bin\\Release\\TEMP.html\"

    string tempTest = "\"" + browserPaths[1] + "\"";//after this line tempTest == \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"
    Process.Start(tempTest, ffTempFilePath);//launch FF
}
```

Comment: That exception is raised if the first argument of Start() is an empty string.

Comment: How exactly do you determine the installation path of the browser? What is the value of `ffTempFilePath` and `browserPaths[1]` I am going to take an educated guess that the actual values of those variables is not what your expecting.

Comment: I did step through Ramhound, but as I said, the problem does not appear when I debug :( I determine the installation path by prompting the user to enter it the first time the application is launched. It is then stored and read from a text file after that.

Comment: Why exactly do you have a `\` after the filename?  There isn't any way this code would work while in debug mode but cause a problem in release mode.

Comment: Process.Start() requires me to have the string inside double quotes as there are spaces in the string. It works in both debug and release mode in VS 2012, it's only after installing it that the behaviour changes.

Comment: @gaynorvader - Post the code that you use to determine the value of `tempFilePath` thats the reason its not working when you install your product.  Of course you really should just determine what the default browser is and launch that.

Comment: You are correct Ramhound, the settings file is only being populated with 1 line. I'll have to look into why that's happening. Thank you for your help. The reason I can't just launch the default browser is that I want to be able to compare the html code in several different browsers easily.

Comment: Turns out that I had only put in \n to end a line in my file instead of \r\n so I was only reading right for IE on line 1 and not for the others on subsequent lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had only put in \n to end a line in my file instead of \r\n so I was only reading right for IE on line 1 and not for the others on subsequent lines